# when I send a delete request it returns "successfully deleted" although when i check my database the item still there?

Tags: node.js

this is the part of my code that handle the delete request and for auth its anothe file to handle the authorization

```
   router.delete("/:id", auth, (req, res) => {
          Contact.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundItem) => {
            if (foundItem) {
              if (foundItem.user.toString() !== req.user.user.id) {
                return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Not autherized" });
              } else {
                Contact.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
                res.json({ msg: "successfully deleted" });
              }
            } else {
              return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Contact not found" });
            }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Most probably you've forgotten to commit/flush the changes to the database no?

Comment: If you specify the database and API you are using (e.g. MongoDB?), it will greatly help us identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem was that the **findByIdAndRemove()** returns a promise and i forgot to handle that so whene ever i use it it shows the msg : "successfully deleted" so i either had to use async and await or use the then() method or use the second parameter of **findByIdAndRemove()**
which is a function that takes 2 params *err* and *deletedItem* the check if the was an *err* if there wasn't then i show my success msg

```
router.delete("/:id", auth, (req, res) => {
  Contact.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundItem) => {
    if (foundItem) {
      if (foundItem.user.toString() !== req.user.user.id) {
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Not autherized" });
      } else {
        Contact.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, deletedItem) => {
          if (deletedItem) {
            res.json({ msg: `successfully deleted ${deletedItem.name}` });
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ msg: "check the console..." });
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Contact not found" });
    }
  });
});
```